# Redirect URLs with sitecore at the end

Tags: url, redirect, sitecore

I would like to ask for your help about redirect with URLs which contains sitecore at the end.
What I want to do is that if my requested URL contains "sitecore" at the end I want redirect this to hostname.

e.g. **www.mySiteName.com/sitecore** redirect to **www.mySiteName.com**.

So I created simple pattern for this as first:

[image: Rule configuration]

then I changed configuration above to only **(.*)(sitecore)$**.

But when I request URL what I get is:

**www.mySiteName.com/sitecore/service/nolayout.aspx?item=%2fsitecore&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default**

instead www.mySiteName.com.

I dont understand why this behaves like this.

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: if you just navigate to www.mysitename.com does it work? Or do you get the layout not found error?

Comment: if I just navigate to www.mysitename.com it works, site exists. But if I use redirect then I get only layout not found error. I have a little suspicion that problem is caused by linkManager section of the web.config. I used on the server as default provider my custom defined which derived from LinkProvider. On my local machine as default provider I used LinkProvider from Sitecore.Kernel and it redirect works.Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating your condition and potentially redirecting to the wrong reference.

Try

```xml
<conditions>
    <add input={URL} pattern="(.*)sitecore$" />
</conditions>
```